# How to trace which function in Wordpress adds certain code to header?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove most css and scripts added to my Wordpress by plugins and maybe core Wordpress. How can I trace which function adds which line in my page header?
Tried to run search for the lines I want to remove but unsuccessfully. I know already that the code is done through wp_header hook but it does not help finding exact function.

Comment: deactivate plugins then activate one by one, after activating each time check for new code at the header, if u found that unwanted code then go through that plugins files

Comment: I know already which plugins add code, but how can I find exact function in the plugin (or core) which does that?

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17394/how-to-know-what-functions-are-hooked-to-an-action-filter

Answer (score 1):

If you know which plugins add the code you can go through plugin files in wp-content/plugins/plugin-name and find following functions.

```
wp_enqueue_script() 
wp_enqueue_style()
```

Usually it will be together and wrapped in another function which will be called by action:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'name_of_function' );
```

For not loading the scripts just uncomment add_action line.

But please be aware, that those scripts are usually vital for correct function of plugin so you will have to serve them from somewhere else.

Also when disabling wp_enqueue be sure you are not disabling admin scripts which would be loaded by action

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'name_of_function' );
```

To be sure always check parametres of wp_enqueue function where script name should match the script you had previously seen in head section of your site.

Every update of plugin will override the files and therefore enable scripts again

Hope this helps.